apt update sqlite3.OperationalError: cannot start a transaction witin a transaction
I have a Ubuntu 20.04 VPS that started to regularly exhibit high load, is very sluggish and the SSH server not responding.
The journalctl command is filled with ssh: error: select: Bad file descriptor (but that's another question.
In my attempt to fix this, I tried to run apt update, but I get this error:
Hit:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
...
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/cnf-update-db", line 26 in <module>
    col.create(db)
  ...
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/db/creator.py", line 161 in _insert_package
    cur=con.execute(''''''
sqlite3.OperationalError: cannot start a transaction witin a transaction
Reading package lists... Error!
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'if /usr/bin/test -w /var/lib/command-not-found/ -a -e /usr/lib/cnf-update-db; then /usr/lib/cnf-update-db > /dev/null; fi'
...

Note: with SSH unavailable I had to copy-paste the output above by hand so there might be typos, or incomplete.
Any idea what is causing this and how to fix it?
